# Default value of CopyToOutputDirectory?

Tags: c#, msbuild

I've been struggling with the lack of information in the documentation for msbuild options.

I need some information concerning Content file option:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-items?view=vs-2019

What is the default value for CopyToOutputDirectory?

```
<Content Include="path/to/file">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

Which option will be used if I omit that second line?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: It either does PreserveNewest or Always. But I don't see the difference between these two, so I don't know which one it's doing

Comment: If you omitted the second line and see the file in your output you probably didn't do a `clean` before testing the effect on the `build`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no 'default' value for `CopyToOutputDirectory`. It is optional and doesn't need to be provided. When not provided (i.e. when you omit your second line) no copy is done.

So the four possibilities for the `CopyToOutputDirectory` metadata are:

- Not provided. No copy is done.
- Provided and set to `Never`. No copy is done.
- Provided and set to `PreserveNewest`. A copy is done only if the file in the output directory is missing or is older.
- Provided and set to `Always`. A copy is always done and the containing project is always run.

If you want to have incremental builds (and locally you probably do), avoid using `Always`.

Comment: It sounds like you are saying that it is the same as "Never".  That would make the default value "Never"

Comment: Only in the sense that it is the same result. But that is not a correct model of what is actually happening. It is two different cases that produce the same result. `CopyToOutputDirectory` is optional and when it is not provided, it is not synthesized with a default value. MSBuild is not "under the covers" adding a hidden `CopyToOutputDirectory="Never"`.

Comment: @JonathanDodds It sounds like you're saying it isn't _literally_ true, but it is conceptually and practically true, which is what anyone not developing or hacking MSBuild would care about